# Using SED to remove specific anchor tags within html in database

Tags: regex, sed

I've got a table which contains hundreds of guides with screenshots. The screenshots images were surrounded by anchor tags as they were clickable before but now I need to remove the anchor tags. All the anchor tags to be removed have an `href=#screenshot` followed by a number as in the example below. My plan is to dump the table using mysqldump and then use **sed** to find and replace the correct strings.

```
<p>Choose <a href="/components">components</a> to install and click next.</p>
<div class="screen">
<a href="#screenshot3"><img src="/images/screens/install/step3.jpg" alt="Step 3"></a>
</div>
```

Should be

```
<p>Choose <a href="/components">components</a> to install and click next.</p>
<div class="screen">
<img src="/images/screens/install/step3.jpg" alt="Step 3">
</div>
```

I can match the first tag using `<a\shref\=\"#screenshot\d+\"\>` but I also need to match its second closing tag so that both can be removed whilst not removing other anchor tags. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing

```
<a\shref\=\"#screenshot\d+\"\>(.*)<\/a>
```

with `\1`.

The parenthesis will capture everything that is found between them so you can restore it using `\1`, `\2`...

Keep in mind though that regexes are not the right weapon to use when trying to modify HTML. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1225541) (and the comments around it) for an explanation.